# ExtJS: Port jQuery plugin ajax file downloader to ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

Looking around I realize that having a nice look & feel ajax downloader file in `ExtJS` is something difficult.

> Even when trying to use `Ext.ux.IFrame`, I found that the `load` event is never fired when you download a file (report, pdf, etc.). If you set the `src` to a website then the `load` event is fired when the page is completed loaded.

So, I found a workaround using a `jQuery` plugin:

http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

> > My goal is to port this `jQuery` plugin to `ExtJS` to now we can add this feature out of the box.

I have never done that before, so I would like to know if there is any guide I can follow in order to port this script.

Appreciate any guide or suggestion.

Comment: This question is way too broad. First you need to understand how the plugin works. Once you do that, you can create something for Ext-JS. The question as it stands, asks us to figure out how the plugin works and how to do the same thing in Ext-JS. What you need to do is try something, if it doesn't work, then you can ask a more specific (answerable) question

Comment: You are right Juan. Let me start looking at it.

Comment: did you port it? I want to do it too! If you have done it before and it is public please let me know

Comment: Yes I ported and is working great.